# Is it allowed to stop and restore I2C transmission?

Tags: communication, i2c, digital-communications

Is it allowed to stop and restore I2C transmission? I would like to stop it in different periods of transmission and then after for example 500ms restore it to the state when it was stopped. I'm thinking about enabling and disabling SCL transitions. If it is allowed, is it a bad practice?

Comment: When debugging I2C communications, this happens accidentally and has been a source of headache for me. Not all devices are particularly good at having arbitrary phases of the I2C clock stretched indefinitely. I quickly learned to always design in a way to generate clocks without a start condition as a means of recovering control after a reset, which helps unless a slave has crashed with `SCL` asserted and held low. Usually there's no recovery from that condition. If you need reliable recovery on a watchdog, watch out for devices like that.

Answer (score 2):

The minimum bus speed for all I<sup>2</sup>C modes is 0Hz. This means that it is valid in the I<sup>2</sup>C specification to stop pulsing the clock (static operation).

However, this does not mean that slaves must also support static operation; they may have internal timeouts which may elapse before communications is resumed. Always check the datasheet of any I<sup>2</sup>C slave devices to verify that they support static operation.

Comment: In datasheet only max frequency is speicfied. The min frequency is left blank. Do u think I can interpret it that the divce support static operation ?

Comment: You need to check the specific behavior of the device. UM10204 specifies 0 Hz, but that is not a per-device guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

I think every I2C must be a fully static design due to clock stretching.

EDIT:

Clock streching is also allowed for masters. Besides, it does not matter who caused it, both, the master and the slave, must handle it correctly. 5 hours is also not reasonable - but it is still within specification.

Comment: Except that clock stretching is performed by slave devices, and 500ms is a bit excessive a stretch under most conditions.